# Is using VPN to do online surveys haram?

Tags: halal-haram, politics

OKay.. here in Pakistan surveys are not much , its some questions and answers but IF I use Vpn to do those surveys honestly but .. wait surveys require honestly and attention so it will be okay If I access those surveys by using VPN to earn money or it will be haram thanks you ... and sometimes its against their policies but sometimes are okay .. maybe

Answer (score 2):

> Is using VPN to do online surveys haram?

It depends what are you doing in surveys. VPN is a tool used for different purposes. Take an example of knife, we can use it to kill somebody but this does not make it haram, only bad acts are haram i.e killing.